# Esse erro acontece quando executo o programa no Ubuntu, sendo que no Win10 funciona normal. O que fazer?

Tags: python, pandas

Programa

```
def trabaLinhas(caminho):
    colunas = extraindoZip.listaArq(caminho)[1]
    dadosV = pd.DataFrame(columns=colunas)
    for coluna in colunas:
        listaLinhas = lerTxt(caminho, coluna)
        dadosVazao = []
        count = 0
    for linha in listaLinhas:
        count += 1
        if count == 1:
            indiceCodigo = linha.index("EstacaoCodigo")
            inicioVa = linha.index("Vazao01")
            indiceData = linha.index("Data")
            indiceCons = linha.index("NivelConsistencia")
        elif count >= 2:
            codigoEst = linha[indiceCodigo]
            data = pd.to_datetime(linha[indiceData], dayfirst=True)
            dias = ca.monthrange(data.year, data.month)[1]
            listaData = pd.date_range(data, periods=dias, freq="D")
            listaCons = [int(linha[indiceCons])]*dias
            indexMult = list(zip(*[listaData, listaCons]))
            index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indexMult, names=["Data", "Consistencia"])
            indiceVa = [i for i in range(inicioVa, inicioVa+dias)]
            listaVazao = [np.NaN if linha[i] == "" else  float(linha[i].replace(",",".")) for i in indiceVa]
            dadosVazao.append(pd.Series(listaVazao, index=index))

    dadosV[coluna] = pd.concat(dadosVazao)
return dadosV
```

---

> File
>   "/home/clebson/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 2272, in _reindex_axes
>       tolerance=tolerance, method=method)
>
> File
>   "/home/clebson/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py",
>   line 1516, in reindex
>       raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
>
> Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: Posta a mensagem do erro junto. "Esse erro" é muito vago.

Comment: Acabei de postar, tinha esquecido.